# How to get video thumbnail form my server?

Tags: android, video

I send some captured videos from my app to my server.

I stored the videos fine.

But my requirement is,i want to get video thumbnails of all videos stored in my server
like face book.

If any one know the solution please help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> This worked for me

```
Bitmap thumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail( videoUrl, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
```